# Where to store Morphlines Java custom command class?

Tags: java, solr, bigdata, etl, cloudera

I have csv files that are indexed in Solr through a Morphline Sink.
I would like to write a custom Java function in Morphlines that hashes one of the csv fields before indexing it into SOLR. 
I tried to adapt this example: http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/04/how-to-process-data-using-morphlines-in-kite-sdk/ (see Import Data into the Hadoop Cluster section)
but I am not sure when i should store the Java class.

So in this example, a publicly available “million song” dataset is picked from Last.fm. the idea is to select songs before and after a given date.

The configuration of the new Morphline command is:

```
morphlines : [
    {
        id : morphline1
        importCommands : ["org.kitesdk.**", "com.sequenceiq.lastfm.etl.**"]
        commands : [
            {
                readJson {
                    outputClass : java.util.Map
                }
            }
            {
                latestSongs {
                    field : timestamp
                    operator: >
                    pattern: "2011-08-03"
                }
            }
        ]
    }]
```

And the corresponding Java code:

```
@Override
protected boolean doProcess(Record record) {
    Map attachmentBody = (Map) record.get(Fields.ATTACHMENT_BODY).get(0);
    String fieldValue = attachmentBody.get(fieldName).toString();

    try {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

        Date fieldDate = sdf.parse(fieldValue);
        Date patternDate = sdf.parse(pattern + " 00:00:00");

        if (operator.equals(HIGHER)) {
            if (!fieldDate.after(patternDate)) {
                return true;
            }
        } else if (operator.equals(LOWER)) {
            if (!fieldDate.before(patternDate)) {
                return true;
            }
        } else if (operator.equals(EQUALS)) {
            if (fieldDate.getYear() != patternDate.getYear()
                    || fieldDate.getMonth() != patternDate.getMonth()
                    || fieldDate.getDay() != patternDate.getDay()) {
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            LOG.info("bad operator syntax");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.info("parse exception: " + e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
    record.removeAll(Fields.ATTACHMENT_BODY);
    try {
        record.put(Fields.MESSAGE, OBJECTMAPPER.writeValueAsString(attachmentBody));
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        LOG.info("parse exception: " + e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
    return super.doProcess(record);
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need to compile the custom java class into a jar file. e.g. via 'mvn package' as shown here: https://github.com/kite-sdk/kite-examples/tree/master/kite-examples-morphlines

Then add the jar file to the java classpath, e.g. by copying the jar file into the lib/
 dir.